# C++ cannot find stdafx.h

Tags: c++, windows, stdafx.h

My program was working fine until I decided to rename one of the directories in where I have my projects. I tried changing the name back to the original but now it's giving me problems where it can't find .h files when their obviously still there in the project explorer. The first one it tells me is that it cannot find stdafx.h

Comment: Could you include the exact compiler error message and the referencing line for our benefit?  stdafx.h is the default precompiled header and needs to be included as the first file in every .cpp you compile that uses the precompiled header.

Comment: ------ Build started: Project: WorldScrollingGame, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  stdafx.cpp
  WorldLayer.cpp
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'WorldLayer.h': No such file or directory Viewport.cpp
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory TiledLayer.cpp
...
It goes on and on, i cant post the whole thing because its too long

Comment: its so annoying because I can see the the code to the files it cant find for some reason. I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but it dosen't do anything.

Comment: Is WorldLayer.cpp in a different directory from these header files?  If so, are you specifying the location of the header files via /I to the compiler or in the INCLUDE environment variable?

Comment: Yes, WorldLayer.cpp is in a diffrent directory then my stdafx.h. I do use #include "stdafx.h"in the WorldLayer.h

Comment: stdafx.h should only be included from files that are given directly to the compiler on the command line (i.e. your .cpp files).  It literally must be the very first thing the compiler encounters in these source files if they're configured to use the precompiled header (anything that comes before the directive will be silently ignored).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.80).aspx is a good reference on the difference between #include "" and #include <>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and just spent the last 30min copying an old version and replacing the old version with the newer code files. Visual Studio should have some type of feature to rescan your project to make sure the directories line up with the current directories.